# How do I stop a Top Terminal Code after executing it once?

Tags: java, ubuntu, terminal

I want to see the CPU and RAM utilisation of a machine , until my java code is running. So I used top command, but I don't know how and when to stop it??

I don't know, how `waitFor()` can work for me?
I might run my code in a thread, but how do I tell it to wait for this thread to finish execution and stop?

MyCode

```
import...*;

public class MyCode {

    ThreadSubclass thread1 = new ThreadSubclass();
        thread1.start();
        /*
          I want Mycode to Run in parallel while top command stores output of RAM and CPU usage.
          Can I write my code here??
          When myCode is complete, stop Top command.
        */
        System.out.println("0"); 

        Process cmdProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("top");
        System.out.println("1"); 
        BufferedReader stdoutReader = new BufferedReader(
                 new InputStreamReader(cmdProc.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = stdoutReader.readLine()) != null) {
           // process procs standard output here
            System.out.println(line); 
        }
        System.out.println("2"); 
        BufferedReader stderrReader = new BufferedReader(
                 new InputStreamReader(cmdProc.getErrorStream()));
        while ((line = stderrReader.readLine()) != null) {
           // process procs standard error here
            System.out.println(line); 
        }
        cmdProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Ctrl+C");
}
```

in another file… `ThreadSubclass.java`

```
public class ThreadSubclass extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
       //Should I write all my code here? I had used fork earlier and it gave me pid, so It was easier for me to run my code inside that if condition of fork pid.

        System.out.println("ThreadSubclass is running");
    }

}
```

Current Output:

0

ThreadSubclass is running

1

2

TERM environment variable not set.

Expected OutPut:

0

ThreadSubclass is running

1

2

Top command output

Issues:

1. If I started "top" command first it didn't goes down to execute other commands.
2. As shown in this code, when I started Thread first, it shows "TERM environment variable not set."
3. if possible store it in a text file directly, rather than reading and storing it inside java code.

```
Process cmdProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("top -b > Top.csv");
```

```
error => 
top: unknown option '>'
Usage:
  top -hv | -bcHiOSs -d secs -n max -u|U user -p pid(s) -o field -w [cols]
```

Comment: If you run `man top` you should the parameters to run it in batch mode and to run with a set number of iterations.  http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/top.1.html

Comment: setting fix number of iterations of top command, won't help as my java code may run of hours. I want top command to stop only when my actual java code stops.

Comment: `top` is extremely CPU and OS intensive.  Running for hours is not wise as it might skew your performance.  If you only care about CPU and memory why not run `ps` against your java process instead?

Comment: I need to analyse some other programs that I am calling from java, so I need to see overall CPU, RAM and DISK usage. and the which process is using it? The pid of processes also changes so . I would need a better way to store these logs, if you have another better option for this situation. I am also trying to setup "sar"